# Detect short or long mouse event in BGE

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I am creating a product user interface mock-up, which has a series of buttons which will be navigated using a mouse. I would like to add a timer to one of the buttons to detect short and long button presses (>2 sec) of the left mouse button to set different actions accordingly.

For example:

sensor detects left mouse press > and > scene actuator sets camera to CAM1

sensor detects long mouse press > and > scene actuator sets camera to CAM2

How could I detect /differentiate between these two types of mouse click, and set the corresponding action?

I don't know how to use python, but happy to try with clear instructions : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question! I was sure this is possible with logic bricks only. Check out the *.blend with a minimal example:

[image]

There are two actions:

- AC_1: Turn cube by 1 Degree
- AC_2: Turn cube by 20 Degree

The cube has a property "prop" initialized by 5, which decreased on every positive pulse when the left mouse button is pressed.

The releasing event for the left mouse button is detected by the M_RELEASE sensor and is connected to three controllers doing the following:

- Executing AC_1 in case the property was larger than zero
- Executing AC_2 in case the property was smaller than zero
- Resetting the property back to 5

There should be a lean solution using Python as well. Maybe someone else has this at hand as a Plan B.

Have fun!

[image]